# JSP+Struts: Handle session timeout in AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts2, servlet-filters, session-timeout

I am making ajax calls from my JS methods to invoke the action class's methods in the following manner:

```
$.getJSON("treeDemo_!getRootNode?appId=" + applicationId, function () {
    }).success(function (e) {
    }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }).complete(function () {
    });
```

Session configuration in my web.xml looks like this

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Now when the session expires after 1 minute, the ajax call returns error (without calling the action method). The error says

```
textStatus = parsererror
errorThrown = SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

But this looks like a generic error. I want to catch the session timeout exception and redirect the user to the login.jsp page in case this exception occurs.

I even tried handling it by doing [this](http://javaj2eetechie.blogspot.in/2009/08/redirecting-to-jsp-page-after-user.html). But it didn't work for me.

Can you please suggest how should I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There's no " session timeout exception ".

Your Ajax call is expecting to get JSON back, nothing in your app sends JSON back if there's a session timeout. Use a filter or interceptor as in the link, check for session timeout, handle normally if it's a normal request, but if it's an Ajax request send back an HTTP error code.

Handle this error code in your JavaScript callbacks.

Comment: Thanks Dave. But like I mentioned, I followed the steps and created a filter in exactly the same way as mentioned in the link. But when the session times out, the control does not reach the `doFilter()` as it should ideally(I guess). And since I am making AJAX calls, I thought that might be the reason why the filter is not working. Any help on this?

Comment: @DarkKnightFan It can't "not reach the filter" unless you defined your filter wrong, like by putting it after the S2 filter or something.